# Removing known audio signal from unknown stream

Tags: noise

I am looking for a way to remove a known signal, A, of fixed length, from an unknown audio stream, B, when signal A can be mixed into signal B at any point in time. I may be mistaking but converting signal A to the frequency domain and performing an STFT where the window is approximately the size of the data buffer of signal B then subtracting these wouldn't work because the amount of signal A that may be contained in signal B is unknown.

Simply, i want to do live noise removal, when the noise is known. What are some methods of approaching this?

Comment: Maybe cross correlation might be a better option.

Comment: So, I'll check how similar the signals are using cross correlation and then based off that, perform spectral subtraction?

Comment: It will tell you at what time A and B are most similar, and I think that peak also can tell you the magnitude.

Comment: I would suggest to also try this [NMF approach](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/48054/8202). It depends on a type of the signals but it should generally work well.

Comment: With regards to that approach, will that work if you are using an audio stream and only have a snippit of the data that you want to denoise in a buffer, or does it only work on two known sources?